# Is there any easy way of making "componentDidUpdate()" lifeycycle method from ONLY JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, methods, lifecycle

I wanted to make my own componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method from JavaScript scratch. How did React do it? How did Vue.JS make their own lifecycle methods. I tried studying the Vue.JS minified version but it confused me a lot. If you can please tell me, thank you. Something similar to below.

```
Element.prototype.whenUpdated = function() {
  /*some codes here that runs when the HTML element is updated*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is only possible (and only really makes sense) in the context of a view framework, one where the state of an element is held inside the framework, and changes to the view stem from changes to the framework's state. Changes to the framework's state are exposed through framework methods.

Here's a tiny example of how something like that might look:

```js
// Framework code
class CustomDiv {
  constructor(sel, text) {
    this.container = document.querySelector(sel);
    this.text = text;
    this.update();
  }
  setText(newText) {
    this.text = newText;
    this.update();
  }
  update() {
    this.container.textContent = this.text;
    this.updateCallback?.();
  }
}

// Interact with the framework...
const customDiv = new CustomDiv('.container', 'initial text');
customDiv.updateCallback = () => {
  console.log('updated!');
};
setTimeout(() => {
  customDiv.setText('new text');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

While there does exist MutationObserver, which can observe changes to a *native* element's contents and attributes and such, that's an entirely different thing.